# CVS - Create Zip when comparing

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

When performing a compare of a CVS vs a local copy of my code, I am looking for a way to create a zip file of the difference.

Example

```
**CVS Files**
File1.java
File2.java

**Local Files**
File1.java
File2.java
File3.java
```

If I perform a compare of the CVS vs Local code, it will find that File3.java is new, and that File2.java has changed. File1.java is unchanged so does not show up when comparing.
As a result of this compare, I am looking for a way that CVS/Eclipse will create a zip file containing File3.java and File2.java. (ignoring File1.java as nothing has changed)

I didn't see anything while browsing the CVS man or the Eclipse plugin website.

This will mostly be used for code reviews as a simple way to package files to send.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean "create a zip file containing _File3.java_ and File2.java"?

Comment: yep. If I have changed code, I want that whole file in the zip. edited the question to correct that typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the quickest method was to perform a compare. Export the compare to a folder. Then zip the corresponding folder.
Not the most efficient, but quicker then manually looking through the folders for my files.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to attempt to package up the output of [`cvs diff`](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/diff.html) from the command line? Not sure why you would need Eclipse to do this.

There are a number of code review tools that have plugins for Eclipse, like [ReviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/), [Code Collaborator](http://smartbear.com/codecollab.php), and [Crucible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/) - perhaps it'd be easier to use an existing tool.

Comment: in the end, I don't care how I get this done as long as it is correct and efficient. Let me check out these other tools to see what they are capable of. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Eclipse has an option to generate a [patch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix\)) (under the `Team` menu) of your current change - you might want to look into this as well.

Comment: Should note as well, that Code review wont be the only use of the zip file.